# How to evaluate this expression: $∫\frac{\sin2x}{(1 - \cos2x)^4}\:\mathrm{d}x$?

Tags: calculus

> How to evaluate: $$∫\frac{\sin2x}{(1 - \cos2x)^4}\:\mathrm{d}x$$ If anyone knows the answer, please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace $\displaystyle1-\cos2x$ with $u$ so that $$\frac{du}{dx}=2\sin2x\iff\sin2x\ dx=\frac{du}2$$

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\cos 2x=\cos^2 x-\sin^2 x$ so $1-\cos 2x=2\sin^2 x$ and $\sin 2x =2\sin x \cos x$. So you end up integrating $$\frac {2\sin x\cos x}{(2\sin^2 x)^4}=\frac {\cos x}{8\sin^7 x}$$

Then if we substitute $y=\sin x$ then we can write $dy = \cos x dx$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int \frac{\sin 2x dx}{(1 - \cos 2x)^4} = \frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\sin 2x d(2x)}{(1 - \cos 2x)^4} = \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{d(1 - \cos 2x)}{(1 - \cos 2x)^4} = \frac{1}{2}\int u^{-4}du
$$
$$
= -\frac{1}{6}(\cos 2x)^{-3} = -\frac{1}{6\cos^3(2x)} + C
$$

Answer (score 0):

Use $1-\cos 2x=2\sin^2 x$ and $\sin 2x=2\sin x\cos x$, then u will get

$$\int \frac{\sin 2x}{(1-\cos 2x)^4}dx=\int \frac{\cos x}{2^3 \sin ^7x }dx$$
Now letting $u=\sin x\Rightarrow du=\cos x dx$
$$\int \frac{\cos x}{2^3 \sin ^7x }dx= \frac{1}{2^3}\int\frac{du}{u^7}=\frac{1}{2^3}.\frac{-1}{6u^6}+C=\frac{1}{2^3}.\frac{-1}{6\sin^6x}+C=\frac{-1}{2^4.3\sin^6x}+C$$